# Formal consequences of homotopy pushouts on homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Below, "homotopy pushout" is defined via weak homotopy equivalences (as opposed to homotopy equivalences).

Fix a homology theory. In [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/250565/69037) an excerpt from a paper of Goodwillie is given which states that a homotopy pushout square induces isomorphisms on relative homology.

$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} A @>f>> B \\ @VgVV @VV{g^\prime}V\\ C @>>{f^\prime}> X \end{CD}$$

**Questions.**

1. How to prove the above statement?
2. In the context of singular homology, is it possible to give a direct proof? That is, can we prove the above assertion using only invariance under **weak** homotopy equivalence **without** using the excision theorem (or Mayer-Vietoris)?

Below are the relevant diagrams. The right one is defined as the homology of the left one. The claim is that if the square about is a homotopy pushout then the lower right horizontal arrow is an isomorphism. I just don't see how to get from a homotopy pushout to the map induced by the cokernel (quotient).

$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} \mathrm{Ch}(A) @>{\mathrm{Ch}(f)}>> \mathrm{Ch}(B)\\ @V{\mathrm{Ch}(g)}VV @VV{\mathrm{Ch}(g^\prime)}V\\ \mathrm{Ch}(C) @>{\mathrm{Ch}(f^\prime)}>> \mathrm{Ch}(X) \\ @VVV @VVV\\ \operatorname{Coker}\mathrm{Ch}(g) @>>> \operatorname{Coker}\mathrm{Ch}(g^\prime) \end{CD}
\qquad
\begin{CD} \mathrm{H}(A) @>>> \mathrm{H}(B)\\ @VVV @VVV\\ \mathrm{H}(C) @>>> \mathrm{H}(X) \\ @VVV @VVV\\ \mathrm{H}^\text{rel}(g) @>>> \mathrm{H}^\text{rel}(g^\prime) \end{CD}$$

Comment: On 1.: It is relatively easy to prove assuming some kind of excision type result. If $A\to X$ is a subcomplex, then $H_*(X/A, A/A) \cong H_*(X,A)$. If you push out $A\to X$ along a cellular map $A\to Y$, then $Y\to P$ is a subcomplex ($P$ is the push out), and $P/Y \cong X/A$ is easy to see.

Comment: Dear @JustinYoung, could you please spell out your very promising comment in an answer? For instance, how to prove $P/Y \cong X/A$? How to reduce to such a pullback square using cellular approximation?

Comment: @JustinYoung also, I don't know how to relate (for a cofibration, say) the relative homology and the homology of the quotient **without** using excision or Mayer-Vietoris.

Comment: I don't think there is any way around excision/Mayer-Vietoris/quotient-relative results.It forms a major part of the engine that makes the calculation of homology possible. Since you can construct a homotopy push out $X \leftarrow A \rightarrow \{*\}$ that computes $X/A$ and the map you are interested in is $H_*(X,A) \to H_*(X/A, A/A)$, this result is essentially equivalent to those results. Thus,the best I can do is prove the result using excision, or else just prove excision again.

Comment: Dear @JustinYoung, for an inclusion of subspaces $\overline U\subset \mathring A\subset X$, is the homotopy cofiber of the inclusion $U\subset A$ weakly homotopy equivalent to its cofiber? Is this inclusion by any chance even a cofibration?

Comment: I don't understand the hypotheses. Are $U$ and $A$ supposed to be any subspaces?

Comment: @JustinYoung yes. (I suspect neither of my assertions is true, but can't think of a counterexample.)

Comment: If you take $A = X = \{0\}\cup \{1/n \mid n\ge 1\}$ and $U = \{1/n \mid n\ge 1\}$. That should be a counterexample to your claims.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the cellular approximation idea:
First, since you are working with a homotopy push out square, you can assume the maps $C \leftarrow A \rightarrow B$ are cofibrations. Therefore, they are inclusions, and then we can build up a CW approximation to the square above

$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} C' @<g'<< A' @>f'>> B' \\ @VVV @VVV @VVV\\ C @<{g}<< A @>f>> B\end{CD}$$ The vertical maps are all weak equivalences.

This is proven in May, Concise: https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/CONCISE/ConciseRevised.pdf in the theorem on p.78 at the start of section 6. The maps on top, $A' \to B'$ and $A' \to C'$ are subcomplexes. The induced map on pushouts $X' \to X$ is a weak equivalence because each is a homotopy pushout. We can similarly see that the induced vertical maps on quotients:

$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} C'/A' @>>> X'/B'  \\ @VVV @VVV \\ C/A @>>> X/B \end{CD}$$ are also weak equivalences. The top horizontal map is easily seen to be a bijection ($X' = C'\cup_{A'} B'$), and the CW topology tells you it is a homeomorphism. Thus, the bottom horizontal map is a weak equivalence.