# Confused about maps of pairs

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homology-cohomology

Suppose we have a pushout:

[image]

What conditions do we need on $f$ or $g$ so that $H^*(X,A)=H^*(Y,B)$?

Comment: The older question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2784801/formal-consequences-of-homotopy-pushouts-on-homology) seems relevant, as does the linked MO question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250565/homotopy-pullbacks-relative-homotopy-groups-vs-homotopy-pushouts-relative-homolo).

Comment: Would you not want $H_*(Y,A) \cong H_*(X,B)$? For this the key term is "homotopy cocartesian" for example when $g$ (or $f$) is a closed inclusion of $CW$ complexes, the isomorphism in my comment will hold